# DAX Cluster - How does it know which DynamoDB Table to talk to?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have just started learning about using DAX for DynamoDB. While the architecture is clear - no where during the setup of DAX did I find it point to a DynamoDB cluster in its setup.
How does DAX know which DynamoDB table to connect if all we're providing from the client is the DAX endpoint?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAX has [same interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.html) as using regular AWS SDK to work with DynamoDB.

So, just like when you query regular DynamoDB, you specify table at each query. For example, [in python](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.client.run-application-python.03-getitem-test.html):

```
# dyn_resource will be reference to your DAX cluster
table = dyn_resource.Table('TryDaxTable')
table.get_item(...)
```